# regex replace all occurances of one character?

Tags: php, regex

Lots of topics on this but i can't figure it out, looking for some tips, shouldn't be that difficult.

I have filename:

```
test_file_from_mpc.mp4_snapshot_13.29_[2015.05.13_21.10.11].jpg
```

i'm trying to use regex to replace the characters _ and then everything starting from snapshot

I got snapshot covered, but i can't seem to get how to catch all the occurances of _ to be selected

```
(_)(snapshot)(.*)
```

selects only 1 _

I read that . should select "any single character" not sure how to use this properly or if it is what i am looking for.

Any guidance would be great! (this is probably 100% a dupe but i have checked all the suggested threads without finding the solution to this seemingly easy problem!)

Comment: what's d expected output?

Comment: duh my bad, expected output would be: test file from mpc mp4

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment yet, but for regex to match more than one occurrence, you need the g - global modifier.

```
/(_snapshot.*$|_|\.)/gi
```

https://regex101.com/r/aI7fF8/2

If you replace purely with space all matching occurences, remember to trim last space.

Here's a php sample as well

```
<?php
$str = "test_file_from_mpc.mp4_snapshot_13.29_[2015.05.13_21.10.11].jpg";
$res = preg_replace(array("/_snapshot.*$/", "/[_.]/"), array("", " "), $str);
print $res; // test file from mpc mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
snapshot.*$|[_.]
```

You can try this.Replace by `space`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/13

```
$re = "/snapshot.*$|[_.]/im"; 
$str = "test_file_from_mpc.mp4_snapshot_13.29_[2015.05.13_21.10.11].jpg"; 
$subst = " "; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: interesting, ways of removing the dot?

Comment: very nice, the switch after closing the regex is new to me, yeah im a newbie at this, didnt see that option, thank you i will try to implement this in a working fashion :)

Comment: hmmm this will not translate into what i was hoping to in production return 
`  return preg_replace(array('/snapshot.*$|_/img', ' ', ' '), get_image_value('image_filename'));
` returns blank values, preg_replace isn't correct for this regex?

Comment: i'm trying to modify this original php code: `preg_replace(array('/\.jpg$/i', '/_/', '/-/'), array('', ' ', ' '), get_image_value('image_filename'));` and i'm trying like this :   `return preg_replace(array('/_snapshot.*$|_|\./gi', '/_snapshot.*$|_|\./gi', '/_snapshot.*$|_|\./gi'), array('', '', ''), get_image_value('image_filename'));` i won't need the array if the first regex does what i expect it to, the original code removes jpeg and some other stuff.

Comment: @karnehe you cn use `return preg_replace(array('/snapshot.*$/i', '/[._]/'), array('', ' '), get_image_value('image_filename'))`

Comment: that works, but i wish i had a clue how it works.... however how would you go about adding a spacer to the dot? isn't the second array line the "replacement" parts what the regex should replace the things it finds with? added space to both of them and still no space for the dot.

Comment: it does add a space now i see but it adds it at the end of mp4 for some reason using this line `return preg_replace(array('/snapshot.*$/i', '/[._]/'), array(' ', ' '), get_image_value('image_filename'));` ideas?

Comment: @karnehe `return preg_replace(array('/_snapshot.*$/i', '/[._]/'), array(' ', ' '), get_image_value('image_filename'));`

Comment: sorry to say same result, the removed dot will not leave a spacer!

Comment: found the issue, it has to do with that the preg_replace is an array, it runs the regex more then once and the filename changes under as it's run, trying to figure out how to combine `/snapshot.*$/i [._]` in one regex instead of using them in an array, if i remove the array and only use `/\./´it replaces the dot with a space.

Comment: @karnehe you can do it in multple steps

Answer (score 0):

Another (potentially faster, but not prettier) way would be to use explode() & implode().

```
// Split string by underscores
$pieces = explode('_', $filename);

// Get the number of pieces
$n = count($pieces);

// Keep just the file extension in the last piece
$pieces[$n] = substr($pieces[$n], strpos($pieces[$n], '.'));

// Remove the other unwanted pieces
unset($pieces[$n - 1];
unset($pieces[$n - 2];

// Reassemble with spaces instead of underscores
$new_string = implode(' ', $pieces);
```